# HAProxy Networking Issue

Tags: c#, httpclient, haproxy

I'm building a .NET application that needs to send web service messages to a 3rd party. Authentication will be done by mutual SSL authentication. The 3rd party have said that they use a HAProxy load balancer for SSL termination.

When I send a message, the first message succeeds (HTTP 200) and all subsequent messages fail (HTTP 503 - service unavailable), until either;
A. I wait for a period of time - approx 5 mins and send again
B. Restart my client application process and send again
After either A or B, the first message works and all subsequent messages fail, and so on...

I have tried sending messages with a couple of applications - Fiddler, my application and another mock, I always get the same behavior. The same thing happens when we run the client from different locations / operating systems.

The client is built on .NET 4.5 and depends on the frameworks HttpClient. According to the documentation for this class "{...} every HttpClient instance uses its own connection pool, isolating its requests from requests executed by other HttpClient instances.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

I am creating a new instance for each request. When I run a Wireshark trace, I see that each message has a new port from my end, and that there is a TCP handshake, so I think it is indeed creating a new connection for each message...

My question is, how can the server recover itself when I reset my client application process. If it's a new stateless TCP connection in each case, how would the server know that messages were coming from the same process?

Thanks in advance,
Rob.

P.S. Here's and example HTTP request/response of the first and second message;

**FIRST MESSAGE**

```
POST https://xxxxxx/xxxxxxx HTTP/1.1

Host: xxxxxxxxxx:9001

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 547

Keep-Alive: false

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
{.....}




HTTP/1.1 200 OK

X-Powered-By: Express

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Content-Type: application/xml

Content-Length: 891

Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 09:02:35 GMT

Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
{...}
```

**SECOND MESSAGE**

```
POST https://xxxxxx/xxxxxxx HTTP/1.1

Host: xxxxxxxxxx:9001

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 547

Keep-Alive: false


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
{.....}



HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Cache-Control: no-cache

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```

Comment: *"I am creating a new instance for each request."*  It seems like the first question is "what happens if you *don't* do that?"  Do multiple requests then work?  What has the other side offered by way of explanation of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I use the same instance of the HttpClient for multiple requests the symptoms are the same (1x 200/ok, multiple 503/service unavailable).

In the end the 3rd party removed a haproxy assertion that the auth cert was presented on every call. This fixed the issue.

It's odd, as my client code was creating a new HttpClient for every request, and was attaching a client certificate for each new HttpClient.

```
    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (this.client = new HttpClient(this.InitialiseHandler()))
        {
            this.SetupRequest();
            this.SendRequest();
            this.RenderResponse();
        }
    }

    private WebRequestHandler InitialiseHandler()
    {
        var handler = new WebRequestHandler
        {
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
            UseProxy = false,
        };

        var clientCert = this.GetClientCertificate();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCert);

        handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += this.ValidationCallback;

        return handler;
    }
```

Prior to getting it working, the first request generated the following few packets (PCAP via Wireshark);

```
     1. Me --> Them    TCP     [SYN]
     2. Them --> Me    TCP     [SYN, ACK]
     3. Me --> Them    TCP     [ACK]
     4. Me --> Them    TCP     [PSH, ACK]  ... Len=130
     5. Them --> Me    TCP     [ACK]       ... Len=1460
```

...the second and subsequent (failing requests), generated the following few packets;

```
     1. Me --> Them    TCP     [SYN]
     2. Them --> Me    TCP     [SYN, ACK]
     3. Me --> Them    TCP     [ACK]
     4. Me --> Them    TCP     [PSH, ACK]  ... Len=1426
     5. Them --> Me    TCP     [PSH, ACK]  ... Len=113
     6. Them --> Me    TCP     [PSH, ACK]  ... Len=272
     7-9 {...} [PSH, ACK] back and forward
     10. Me --> Them   TCP     [FIN, ACK]
     11. Them --> Me   TCP     [FIN, ACK]
     12. Me --> Them   TCP     [ACK]
     13. Them --> Me   TCP     [RST]
```

I can't understand the data in the 4th packet, it appears to be cipher. I can't figure out why there is such a big different in length between the first and second requests.

With the change to the HAProxy configuration, the initial request generates the same few packets as before. Subsequent requests deviate from the example shown above on the 6th packet;

```
      6. Me --> Them    TCP     [PSH, ACK]  ... Len=256
      7. Them --> Me    TCP     [ACK]
      {...}
```